# Semantic-UI Pre-load data in dropdown by selected attribute in rendered HTML

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

My dropdown data contains duplicates and I also need to pre-select the data on load. Due to having duplicate options with same values, the default binding for dropdowns using Semantic-UI was failing.

Here is how my data looks

```
<select id="P861" data-cell="P861" class="ui search selection dropdown">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Insufficient information</option>
  <option value="1">Not applicable</option>
  <option value="1">No</option>
  <option value="3">Partially</option>
  <option value="4">Yes</option>
  <option value="4">Not Applicable</option>
</select>
```

When binding this with Semanticui

```
//for example 
$('#P861').dropdown();
```

The dropdown binding selects **No** instead of **Insufficient information**, since that is the last option with the same value - **1**, which is incorrect in my use case.

Almost all dropdowns use ids or unique values for the option values. But in my current system, these dropdowns are pre-defined by a user based on data from a VLOOKUP table in an excel file (system conversion from excel to MVC), and hence the values can be duplicate in this case.

I didn't find any answer anywhere on the net or stack overflow since this is a very unique case, hence decided to fix this by myself.

Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a separate condition which overrides finding the selected item in the DIV.Menu that is generated by semantic-ui by searching for the selected item's text instead of value. This change was made directly in the semantic.js file (local copy).

Please note - this change is inside the framework JS file and I would not recommend this to anyone unless they know for sure that they are not going to upgrade the Semantic UI Framework file, as these changes would be lost.

**Code Changes**

At line 8660 of fomanticUI - semantic.js version 2.8.6, I added the following:

```
if (shouldSearch) {
    //Custom code for selecting based on selected attribute of rendered option instead of value

    //Find the selected option inside $module, $module is the select tag by default.
    var selByText = $module.find('option[selected="selected"]');

    //If the option with selected attribute exists
    if (selByText !== undefined && selByText.length > 0) {
      //$item at this method will be the array of items inside the DIV.Menu 
      //and From the parent level - DIV.Menu, find the option that contains the data-text as the 
      //selected text above.
      $selectedItem = $item.parent().find('div.item[data-text="' + selByText[0].outerText + '"]');
    }
    else {
        //existing code *$item.each(function (){ code... });* within **if(shouldSearch)**
        //this allows that if your dropdown data doesn't have 
        //any selected="selected" attribute, then the default code will run.
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for a similar fix, as this was quite a challenging piece to implement, as I had to debug the entire binding process of the dropdown to find this out.